# Rails migrate stopped working after upgrading to 4.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I did:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/rails4$ rails generate migration Posts title:string content:text
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

And then nothing happens. I just updated to Rails 4.0.0. And I'm in a normal Rails app:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/rails4$ ls
app  config     db       Gemfile.lock  log     Rakefile     test  vendor
bin  config.ru  Gemfile  lib           public  README.rdoc  tmp
alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/rails4$
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: did you run `rake rails:update:bin`?

Comment: @Michael Szyndel Werid, I discovered I hadn't installed rake. Strange, I thought rails new also did bundle install.

Comment: So did this solve the problem? Maybe I add an answer for future reference?

Comment: @Michael Szyndel Yes, by doing bundle install. Can you add an answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

and then

```
bundle install
```